# iTextSharp creating a pdf but only the English words/letters are written

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

I want to include the gibrish (Hebrew) words and letters to the pdf, but, it’s creating the pdf without the Hebrew language.

Thanks for helping and for the helpers!!

That’s my code

```
    public void createPDF(DataTable dataTable, string destinationPath)
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
var Font = FontFactory.GetFont(“Tahoma”, 12);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataTable.Columns.Count);
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    //Set columns names in the pdf file
    for(int k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Columns[k].ColumnName, Font));

        cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(51, 102, 102);

        table.AddCell(cell);
    }

    //Add values of DataTable in pdf file
    for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString(), Font));

            //Align the cell in the center
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
    }

    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: The font change to the desire language or remove and see .I am not sure in case of emove

Comment: @NivZiv Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
var Font = FontFactory.GetFont(“Tahoma”, 12);
```

which retrieves a font object using many default settings, in particular the encoding **WinAnsiEncoding**. This encoding is similar to Latin-1, in particular it does not contain Hebrew characters.

For support of a wide range of characters, try **Identity-H** instead:

```
var Font = FontFactory.GetFont(“Tahoma”, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 12);
```

Furthermore, you have to make sure that your copy of the font includes Hebrew characters (Tahoma most likely does but there are numerous fonts that don't).